# Check if display none is added to element via jquery

Tags: jquery, css, hide

I am trying to add a script that hides and element when another one is hidden.

```
if (jQuery('#thisElement').css('display') == 'none') {
// DO SOMETHING 
}
```

but since the element is already hidden (adding style="display:none") via javascript/ jquery, my script does not work.
Is there a workaround?
I cannot hide using css.

Maybe I should use mutationobserver?

Comment: Why are you trying to hide the element if it is already hidden, can you make the question clearer?

Comment: Have you tried JS getComputedStyle

Comment: @Neon I need to hide another element based on some conditions.

Comment: "*but since the element is already hidden my script does not work*" - can you elaborate?  Ideally provide an example html/js to set up the scenario. If you're trying to hide something that's already hidden, then it "works" in that the end result is that it's hidden.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without jquery but since you asked specifically using jquery, you can hide it this way.

```
if($('#thisElement').css('display') == 'none')
{
    $("#otherElement").css("display", "none");
}
```